# Displaying date in a required format in django Modelform

Tags: django, modelform

I have the following:

Model:

```
class customer(models.Model):
    cstid = models.AutoField(primary_key=True, unique=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=35)
    ageyrs=models.IntegerField(blank=True)
    agemnths=models.IntegerField(blank=True)
    dob = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True)
    gender_choices = (('male', 'Male'),
        ('female', 'Female'),
        ('other', 'Something else'),
        ('decline', 'Decline to answer'))
    gender = models.CharField(
        choices=gender_choices, max_length=10, default='male')
    maritalstatus_choices = (('unmarried', 'Unmarried'),
        ('married', 'Married'))
    maritalstatus = models.CharField(
        choices=maritalstatus_choices, max_length=10, default='Unmarried')
    mobile = models.CharField(max_length=15, default='')
    alternate = models.CharField(max_length=15, default='', blank=True)
    email = models.CharField(max_length=50, default='', blank=True)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=80, default='', blank=True)
    city = models.CharField(max_length=25, default='', blank=True)
    occupation = models.CharField(max_length=25, default='', blank=True)
    bloodgroup_choices = (('apos', 'A+'),
        ('aneg', 'A-'),
        ('bpos', 'B+'),
        ('bneg', 'B-'),
        ('opos', 'O+'),
        ('oneg', 'O-'),
        ('abpos', 'AB+'),
        ('abneg', 'AB-')
        )
    bloodgroup = models.CharField(choices=bloodgroup_choices, max_length=5, default='-', blank=True)

    class Meta:
        unique_together = ["name", "mobile", "linkedclinic"]
```

My ModelForm:

```
class RegisterPatientMetaForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        dob = forms.DateField(input_formats=['%d-%m-%Y'])
        model = customer
        fields = [
            'name',
            'ageyrs',
            'agemnths',
            'dob',
            'gender',
            'maritalstatus',
            'mobile',
            'alternate',
            'email',
            'address',
            'city',
            'occupation',
            'bloodgroup'
            ]
```

In my template, I have:

```
<div class="col-md-8">
    <label for="gender">Date of Birth</label>
    {{ form.dob }}
</div>
```

The issue is that the date is being displayed as %Y-%m-%d, while I want it to display as %d-%m-%Y. What's wrong with how I am doing it? How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@ruddra's answer was only partly correct.
There are two different aspects to my problem. On one hand, I need to display an existing database row in the chosen date format. For doing this, I needed to customize the forms.DateInput widget so that existing value is displayed correctly. On the second, I needed to accept input in the chosen format too.

So the solution as code was:

```
class RegisterPatientMetaForm(ModelForm):
    dob = forms.DateField(
        input_formats=['%d-%m-%y'],
        widget=forms.DateInput(format='%d-%m-%y')
        )
    class Meta:        
        model = customer
        fields = [
            'name',
            'ageyrs',
            'agemnths',
            'dob',
            'gender',
            'maritalstatus',
            'mobile',
            'alternate',
            'email',
            'address',
            'city',
            'occupation',
            'bloodgroup'
            ]
        error_messages = {           
        }
        unique_together = ["name", "mobile", "linkedclinic"]
```

Here, the `input_formats=['%d-%m-%y']` list decides what date formats are accepted as input(See [Docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/forms/widgets/#django.forms.DateInput)). While the `widget=forms.DateInput(format='%d-%m-%y')` makes the initial field displayed correctly (See [Docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/settings/#date-input-formats))

Answer (score 1):

When you are overriding a field of the form, you need to put it as an attribute of the class, not in the meta class. Like this:

```
class RegisterPatientMetaForm(ModelForm):
    dob = forms.DateField(input_formats=['%d-%m-%Y'])  # <-- removed it from meta and put it here
    class Meta:
        model = customer
        fields = [
            'name',
            'ageyrs',
            'agemnths',
            'dob',
            'gender',
            'maritalstatus',
            'mobile',
            'alternate',
            'email',
            'address',
            'city',
            'occupation',
            'bloodgroup'
            ]
```

Comment: I need to display the data that's already in the form in this format too, not just handle input given in this format.